# Should syslog's openlog() be called before or after seteuid/setegid

Tags: c, permissions, syslog

The code I have calls `openlog()` once, before altering the effective uid/gid of the program (a daemon). From a security standpoint, or a predictability standpoint, would calling `openlog()` after setting the effective uid/gid be better?

I'm guessing on most platforms `openlog()` will open a Unix Socket to syslogd? Are permissions on this likely too restrictive to allow the socket to be opened by system users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps someone has a specific case where `openlog` requires elevated privileges, but I found none (and have in mind `lynx`, which used to have this in its compiled-in default features - up til [2009](http://lynx.isc.org/current/CHANGES.html#v2.8.8dev.1)).  daemons (see [this](http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/CMSC480/Daemons/Daemons.html) page) do not have to run as root, and often use the feature.

The book *[The Hacker's Handbook: The Strategy Behind Breaking into and Defending Networks](https://books.google.com/books?id=AO2fsAPVC34C&pg=PA751&lpg=PA751&dq=%22openlog%22%20privileges&source=bl&ots=LgUvZ8aUH5&sig=u42T3mf6NeUjyb5R3GPRmpwuxWo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DsM8VdThIMengwSrgIHYBA&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22openlog%22%20privileges&f=false)* cites openlog and its associated functions as a vulnerability,

> which allow an attacker to inject "counterfeit" syslog messages into a log file

Given that, ensuring that there are no weaknesses in your application is doubly important (since there is always the possibility of becoming an agent of some other program's intrusion).

So the answer seems to be that no, there may be no *need* to do this, but dropping privileges *early* is always a good rule.  If you find a specific case where you need the privileges, that is the point at which to reconsider their use.